# Can't import image in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, import

Here is my project structure

[image: structure]

I'm trying to display the image from the **static** folder but it can't be displayed.
I also tried to mention the static folder in the **settings.py** file as below:
[image: Settings.py]

Here is how I'm calling the image from the **base.html** file.
[image: base.html]

I'm not sure what is wrong, I tried to search but the google sources can't help.

Comment: paste your code, do not use screenshots

Comment: I thought screenshots makes it much clear

Comment: [ask] , see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Ohhhh I didn't know about this before:( 
Thanks @Scb

Answer (score 1):

The correct format of displaying static images in django would be this

```
{% load static %} 

<img src="{% static 'images/heart1.png' %}">
```

**Edit**

Put the following lines in your `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

add the following to your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               #other urls

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help:)
Just searched and found this is the correct format.

What are the changes should I make?
I think I should change some things in the settings.py file
I tried this source https://www.mytecbits.com/internet/python/addding-image-django-web-app 
but it didn't help

Comment: Check the answer, i have edited it to include how you can configure this, feel free to ask any question about this topic

Comment: Thank you but it still can't help
I'm not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the static template tag in your template

```
{% load static %}
{% static "images/heart1.png" %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm I not supposed to use src=" " ?

Comment: I don't even understand the changes I noticed that I should first make in my URL and settings files.